# How to translate i tag of html into rails' link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to translate below code into link_to helper. How to do that?

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
```

Comment: The <i> tag is not a link, nor does it link to anything. The link target is set in the <a> tag. Take a look at the [rails documentation for `link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) which has some examples that should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recreate the above link by using `link_to`'s block format, like so:

```
<%= link_to "#" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps!